# Is it possible to get a free domain and hosting with email in 2021? Self hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, email, free, wampserver, wamp

I am starting a small company and wanted to have an email address that isn't g*mail etc.

In the past I have been able to achieve my own custom email by using a domain of co.cc (there have been others also but it was many years ago).

I've been trying to look around at free webhosts (I already see Dot TK for the free domain as example). Of course, once I've set it up fully, purchasing a `.com` domain will not be much of a problem. However, all the webhosts I found don't give a free email. And I really cannot afford a monthly fee right now.

Again, many years ago I ran my own website using something called 'WAMPServer'. Thing is I am really busy and sadly not earning enough to even pay for hosting service. I don't have much time to waste hence I am asking here for advice. If WAMPserver or similar is capable of doing the job, I only really need that confirmed. I can then go and learn the steps to set it up by myself.

The thing I am trying to avoid is going down a long rabbit-hole with something like WAMPserver only to find I cannot do what I need.

What is the best way in this day and age to set this up?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The linked answer doesnt address the issue at all. Waste of time

Comment: If you can find a free webhost you can set MX records pointing to gmail and configure gmail to handle your email I believe.  (btw, this is off topic here). WAMP is a web hosting platform. Email requires entirely different - and more complex to set up - infrastructure.

Comment: thanks for the help and suggestion. I will look into that solution